# qmake: How do I copy .dll/.so's to the output directory?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a Qt-project that builds a dll/shared-library and another Qt-project that tests the library.

Is there any good way to have qmake copy the dll to the output-folder of the test-project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your pro file:

```
target.path = ../testProject/$$TARGET
INSTALLS += target
```

Comment: This works only if you run `make install` build step

Comment: This puts the responsibility onto the tested project, to know about the project that tests it -- which is backward.

Answer (score 8):

```
# Copy the dynamic library.
win32 {
   QMAKE_PRE_LINK=copy /Y lib\qextserialport\src\build\qextserialportd.dll debug\ & copy /Y lib\qextserialport\src\build\qextserialport.dll release\
}
else {
   # TODO: Unices
}
```

This works, for the QextSerialPort library. Supports Qt's `debug_and_release` mode.

`QMAKE_POST_LINK` also works, but will throw an error if you're trying to run the app immediately: then your .dll will be copied too late. `QMAKE_PRE_LINK` does copy it in time.

Answer (score 4):

I use INSTALLS, [like so.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs) (qmake documentation)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a 'good' way but it may do the trick.

`QMAKE_POST_LINK += some shell command to copy the dll`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DESTDIR` keyword as it is said in [qmake files documetation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-common-projects.html) in Qt 4.

Comment: This is the other way around - copies the executable to `DESTDIR` (where DLLs might be). It was an even better fit for my case, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$QMAKE_COPY $$quote("yourSrcDir\your.dll") $$quote($$IN_PWD) $$escape_expand(\\n\\t)
```