# Using Qt Creator and Project files, how do I copy a created dll/so with QMAKE_POST_LINK

Tags: qt, qmake

This question appears to be answered in this tread

[qmake: How do I copy .dll/.so's to the output directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740534/qmake-how-do-i-copy-dll-sos-to-the-output-directory)

but it does not work for me.  I'm trying to do this within Qt Creator 2.0.1 with Qt SDK 4.7.0 on Windows 7

If I try:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK=copy /Y \Projects\TestFile.txt \Projects\OSPF\TestFile.txt
```

on even a static file, the output I get is:

```
copy /Y \Projects\TestFile.txt \Projects\OSPF\TestFile.txt
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, copy /Y \Projects\TestFile.txt \Projects\OSPF\TestFile.txt, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I try:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK=cmd.exe /C copy /Y \Projects\TestFile.txt \Projects\OSPF\TestFile.txt
```

The output I get is:

```
cmd.exe /C copy /Y \Projects\TestFile.txt \Projects\OSPF\TestFile.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Does someone know the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests the problem is in the path to the file you want to copy.

I created a simple .pro file and used the same command to copy a file - with the path changed accordingly - and it worked correctly.

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK=copy /Y .\hello.h .\debug\hello.h;
```

it's equivalent to

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK=copy /Y hello.h debug\hello.h;
```

With this command the file hello.h, in the same directory of the .pro file, is copied to the debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

Apprently the copy does not work if you start at the root of your drive.   Go back and look at my example.   I was starting at the root of my current drive.   I also tried

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK=copy /Y $$PWD\MyFile  $$PWD\anotherdir\MyFile
```

That did not work either.

Apprently you have to be relative to you directory????   I'm not sure what the real limitations are.