# Qt application cannot find a 3rd party DLL and crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to build an application in QT that uses the libmodbus library. I am using MinGW 5.3 (Windows 7). The application will build without an error, but crashes when it attempts to run. The debug message says:

> During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135

If I double-click the created executable file, there is an error that says:

> libmodbus-5.dll is missing

from my computer.

Libmodbus was built with the same compiler. The include files are located in `../../codelibrary/MinGW63/libmodbus-master/src` and the linker files are located in `../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src/.libs` (`.libs` folder has both `libmodbus.dll.a` and `libmodbus-5.dll`).

If I add this library with Qt's 3rd party library wizard, then I get the following in my `.pro` file:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src/.libs/ -llibmodbus.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src/.libs/libmodbus.dll.lib
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src/.libs/liblibmodbus.dll.a
```

This gives me the error:

> -1: error: No rule to make target '../../codelibrary/MinGW63/libmodbus-master/src/.libs/liblibmodbus.dll.a', needed by 'debug\QTRosemount.exe'.  Stop.

I then tried changing the `.pro` file to:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src/.libs/libmodbus-5.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src

PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src/.libs/libmodbus.dll.a
```

This is when it will build without error and crash right away with code 0xc0000135 and a missing `libmodbus-5.dll`. I have tried many variations of the `.pro` paths that get this same error.

**Note:** I have been able to run console applications in Codeblocks with this library, not sure what I am running into with Qt.

How to fix this?

Comment: I hope to be not misleading you, but, if copying the DLL manually to the executable directory fixes the executable crash (meaning that all linking/building is correct), did you considered adding a INSTALL or QMAKE_PRE_LINK to [copy the dll to the output location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740534/qmake-how-do-i-copy-dll-sos-to-the-output-directory)?

Comment: Copying the DLL worked manually, thank you! Is adding INSTALL or QMAKE_PRE_LINK arguments common practice when using 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Alert, I am being opinionated! QMake was set as deprecated at [QtCon 2016](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_build_systems_at_QtCon_2016). This made a lot of engineers move to CMake, which is well supported by QtCreator. The best organized Qt projects I worked with would be using INSTALL instead of QMAKE_PRE_LINK, as shown in the [official Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html). Also, I have seen [.pri files](https://wiki.qt.io/Including_.pro_Files) being used to increase readability of .pro files and facilitate re-including common third party libraries in a variety of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an INSTALL SET and append it to the INSTALL list, as shown in [QT documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html) and illustrated below:

```
documentation.path = /usr/local/program/doc
documentation.files = docs/*
INSTALLS += documentation
```

For convenience, you may also use [QMAKE_PRE_LINK](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-pre-link). Now that you have some options, you may find further information in stackoverflow, such as in [posts like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740534/qmake-how-do-i-copy-dll-sos-to-the-output-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I found that DEPENDPATH was incorrect. I have a folder in libmodbus that this needs to point to:

```
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../codelibrary/QtMinGW53/libmodbus-master/src/.deps
```

The program compiles correctly with this changed